# Is there any way to write the client ip and computer name on my server running ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any way to write the client IP and computer name on my server running ASP.NET?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the server variables collection:

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

Specificially remote_host and remote_addr

```
string sHost = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"].ToString();
string sIP = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
```

Comment: sure... string sIP = Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"].ToString();

Comment: REMOTE_HOST and REMOTE_ADDR both return the ip address of the machine.IIS doesn't do reverse DNS lookup by default, you have to configure it.

Answer (score 3):

The client IP address YES: using the [Request.UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx) property, the client computer name: NO

Comment: @Gali, yes, you could use `Request.UserHostAddress` in your `Page_Load` event. It will give you the IP address of the client. What other example do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the client host name, you can use `Request.UserHostName`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sHostName = Request.UserHostName;
    ...
}
```

Note that in some cases (the most obvious case being the client host does not have a host name), the `Request.UserHostName` property will return the client's IP address.